# What is the SocialPushAgent on mac OS X and what does it do?

Tags: macos

Does anyone know what the SocialPushAgent is on Mac OS X ?

Located in: /System/Library/CoreServices/SocialPushAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/SocialPushAgent

What does it do?